# TOAST UI Grid (javascript) error: tui_date_picker_1.default is not a constructor

Tags: user-interface, grid, toast

I am starting to use TOAST UI Grid and I am testing it with a very simple example and I have the following problem:

The datePicker type editor doesn't work.

When the focus is placed on the field corresponding to the date, the error Uncaught TypeError: tui_date_picker_1.default is not a constructor appears and it no longer works.

I don't know how to resolve this error.

Can anyone help me?

These is the complete error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: tui_date_picker_1.default is not a constructor
at new DatePickerEditor (utils.js:69:8)
at EditingLayerComp.createEditor (utils.js:69:8)
at EditingLayerComp.componentDidUpdate (utils.js:69:8)
at renderComponent (customEvents.js:502:1)
at setComponentProps (customEvents.js:372:1)
at renderComponent (customEvents.js:443:1)
at class_1.forceUpdate (_safeEvent.js:18:1)
at class_1.setStateUsingSelector (getTarget.js:18:1)
at Object.fn (off.js:3:1)
at callObserver (off.js:74:1)"
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Federico_Moon/5c0sjb64/3/

```
'use strict'

var lstCountries = [
    { text: "FRANCE", value: '0' },
    { text: "SPAIN", value: '1' },
    { text: "ITALY", value: '2' },
    { text: "GERMANY", value: '3' },
];

var tableData = [
    {
        code: '',
        country: '',
        capital: '',
        date: '',
        email: '',
        phone: ''
    },
];

const grid = new tui.Grid({
    el: document.getElementById('grid'),
    data: tableData,
    rowHeight: 30,
    minRowHeight: 30,
    editingEvent: 'click',
    rowHeaders: [
        { type: 'checkbox', width: 30, align: 'center', valign: 'bottom' },
    ],
    columns: [
        { header: 'Code', name: 'code', sorteable: true, editor: 'text' },
        {
            header: 'Country',
            name: 'country',
            formatter: 'listItemText',
            editingEvent: 'click',
            editor: {
                type: 'select',
                options: {
                    listItems: lstCountries
                }
            }
        },
        {
            header: 'Date',
            name: 'date',
            editor: {
                type: 'datePicker',
                options: {
                  format: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
                  layoutType: 'tab'
                }
              }
            },
        { header: 'email', name: 'email', editor: 'text' },
        { header: 'Phone', name: 'phone', editor: 'text' }
    ],
});
```

Thank you